# Advice on string search with Cuda

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing

I am to write a cuda code which searches set of keyword strings inside set of data strings and returns an array of boolean for keyword-data string pairs.
 Data strings: at the moment, 10000(may vary) strings and each of them has max 250 chars. 
 
Keyword strings: at the moment, 100(may vary) strings and each of them has max 100 chars. 
 
Length of each string is known.
My question is which of the following approaches might be more suitable in this case. 
 
1st:
gridDim.x => # of keyword strings 
 
gridDim.y => # of data strings 
blockDim => (max string size(250 in this case),1,1) 
Naive algorithm will be used for search 
Each thread will load the chars of keyword and data to shared mem from global mem. 
Each thread will be responsible for one of the windows in naive search algorithm. 
 
Result will be written to the boolean array. 
So, each block will be responsible for keyword-data pair. 
2nd:
gridDim => (# of data strings,1,1) 
blockDim => (# of keyword strings,1,1) 
In each block, data string will be loaded to shared mem. 
In this case, each thread will be responsible for keyword-data pair instead of block. 
Each thread will search corresponding keyword inside the data string.
Naive algorithm is not necessary in this case, Boyer-Moore might be used.
For searches inside huge files, since length of the data is much bigger than the length of the keyword, 1st approach is used. But in this case, I am not sure if the 1st appraoch is better. On the other hand, for 2nd approach, coalescing the keywords might be a problem, since the lengths are not fixed. There is an upper boundry for the size of the keywords. So, padding might ease the coalescing but it would consume more memory.
Anyhow, if you have worked on a similar case or know about a better approach than those I described above, please help me out.
Thank you in advance.

So, I've implemented both of the cases. 
 Code for approach 1:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "chrono"
#include "cstdlib"

#define SEARCHTERMSIZE 100
#define SEARCHITEMSIZE 65000
#define MAXDATASTRINGSIZE 250
#define MAXKEYWORDSTRINGSSIZE 50

using namespace std;

__global__ void searchKeywordKernel(bool* resultPtr, const char * dataPtr, const short*  dataLengths, const char *  keywordPtr, const short*  keywordLengths)
{
    int dataIndex = blockIdx.x;
    int keywordIndex = blockIdx.y;
    int dataLength = dataLengths[dataIndex];
    int keywordLength = keywordLengths[keywordIndex];
    __shared__ char sData[MAXDATASTRINGSIZE];
    __shared__ char sKeyword[MAXKEYWORDSTRINGSSIZE];
    __shared__ bool isFound;

    if (dataIndex < SEARCHITEMSIZE && keywordIndex < SEARCHTERMSIZE)
    {
        if (dataLength < keywordLength)
        {
            resultPtr[keywordIndex*SEARCHITEMSIZE + dataIndex] = false;
        }
        else
        {
            isFound = false;
            sData[threadIdx.x] = dataPtr[dataIndex*MAXDATASTRINGSIZE + threadIdx.x];
            if (threadIdx.x < keywordLength)
                sKeyword[threadIdx.x] = keywordPtr[keywordIndex*MAXKEYWORDSTRINGSSIZE + threadIdx.x];
            __syncthreads();

            if (threadIdx.x <= dataLength - keywordLength)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < keywordLength && !isFound; i++)
                {
                    if (sData[threadIdx.x + i] != sKeyword[i])
                        break;
                    if (i == keywordLength - 1)
                        isFound = true;
                }
            }
            resultPtr[keywordIndex*SEARCHITEMSIZE + dataIndex] = isFound;
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    chrono::steady_clock::time_point startTime;
    chrono::steady_clock::time_point endTime;
    typedef chrono::duration<int, milli> millisecs_t;

    //////////Search Data Init/////////////////
    cout << "Before Search Data Init" << endl;
    startTime = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    char* dataPtr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAXDATASTRINGSIZE*SEARCHITEMSIZE);
    short* dataLengths = new short[SEARCHITEMSIZE];
    short temp;
    short tempChar;
    for (int i = 0; i < SEARCHITEMSIZE; i++)
    {
        temp = rand() % (MAXDATASTRINGSIZE - 20) + 20;
        for (int k = 0; k < temp; k++)
        {
            tempChar = rand() % 26;
            dataPtr[i*MAXDATASTRINGSIZE + k] = 97 + tempChar;  //97->a, 98->b, 122->z
        }
        dataLengths[i] = temp;
    }
    endTime = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    millisecs_t duration(chrono::duration_cast<millisecs_t>(endTime - startTime));
    cout << "After Search Data Init: " << duration.count() << "ms" << endl;
    //////////Search Data Init/////////////////

    //////////Search Keyword Init/////////////////
    cout << "Before Search Keyword Init" << endl;
    startTime = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    char* keywordPtr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAXKEYWORDSTRINGSSIZE*SEARCHTERMSIZE);
    short* keywordLengths = new short[SEARCHTERMSIZE]; //lenghts, not the start positions
    for (int i = 0; i < SEARCHTERMSIZE; i++)
    {
        temp = rand() % (MAXKEYWORDSTRINGSSIZE - 10) + 10;
        for (int k = 0; k < temp; k++)
        {
            tempChar = rand() % 26;
            keywordPtr[i*MAXKEYWORDSTRINGSSIZE + k] = 97 + tempChar;  //97->a, 98->b, 122->z
        }
        keywordLengths[i] = temp;
    }
    endTime = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    millisecs_t duration1(chrono::duration_cast<millisecs_t>(endTime - startTime));
    cout << "After Search Keyword Init: " << duration1.count() << "ms" << endl;
    //////////Search Keyword Init/////////////////  

    char* d_dataPtr;
    short* d_dataLengths;
    char* d_keywordPtr;
    short* d_keywordLengths;
    bool* d_resultPtr;

    /////////////////////////CudaMalloc/////////////////////////////////
    cout << "Before Malloc" << endl;
    startTime = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    cudaMalloc(&d_dataPtr, sizeof(char) * SEARCHITEMSIZE * MAXDATASTRINGSIZE);
    cudaMalloc(&d_dataLengths, sizeof(short) * SEARCHITEMSIZE);
    cudaMalloc(&d_keywordPtr, sizeof(char) * SEARCHTERMSIZE*MAXKEYWORDSTRINGSSIZE);
    cudaMalloc(&d_keywordLengths, sizeof(short) * SEARCHTERMSIZE);
    cudaMalloc(&d_resultPtr, sizeof(bool)*SEARCHITEMSIZE * SEARCHTERMSIZE);

    endTime = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    millisecs_t duration2(chrono::duration_cast<millisecs_t>(endTime - startTime));
    cout << "After Malloc: " << duration2.count() << "ms" << endl;
    /////////////////////////CudaMalloc/////////////////////////////////

    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    float elapsedTime;

    /////////////////////////CudaMemCpy///////////////////////////////////
    cout << "Before Memcpy" << endl;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

    cudaMemcpy(d_dataPtr, dataPtr, sizeof(char) * SEARCHITEMSIZE * MAXDATASTRINGSIZE, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_dataLengths, dataLengths, sizeof(short) * SEARCHITEMSIZE, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_keywordPtr, keywordPtr, sizeof(char) * SEARCHTERMSIZE*MAXKEYWORDSTRINGSSIZE, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_keywordLengths, keywordLengths, sizeof(short) * SEARCHTERMSIZE, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsedTime, start, stop);
    cudaEventDestroy(start);
    cudaEventDestroy(stop);
    cout << "After Memcpy: " << elapsedTime << "ms" << endl;
    /////////////////////////CudaMemCpy///////////////////////////////////

    ////////////////////////Kernel//////////////////////////////////////////
    cout << "Before Kernel" << endl;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

    dim3 dimGrid(SEARCHITEMSIZE,SEARCHTERMSIZE);
    searchKeywordKernel << < dimGrid, MAXDATASTRINGSIZE >> >(d_resultPtr, d_dataPtr, d_dataLengths, d_keywordPtr, d_keywordLengths);

    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsedTime, start, stop);
    cudaEventDestroy(start);
    cudaEventDestroy(stop);
    cout << "After Kernel: " << elapsedTime << "ms" << endl;
    ////////////////////////Kernel//////////////////////////////////////////

    bool* result = new bool[SEARCHTERMSIZE*SEARCHITEMSIZE];

    cudaMemcpy(result, d_resultPtr, sizeof(bool) * SEARCHITEMSIZE * SEARCHTERMSIZE, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    /////////////////////////////////// CPU code //////////////////////////////////////////

    bool* cpuResult = new bool[SEARCHTERMSIZE*SEARCHITEMSIZE];

    cout << "CPU code starts" << endl;
    startTime = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < SEARCHTERMSIZE; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < SEARCHITEMSIZE; j++)
        {
            if (dataLengths[j] < keywordLengths[i])
            {
                cpuResult[i*SEARCHITEMSIZE + j] = false;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int k = 0; k <= dataLengths[j] - keywordLengths[i]; k++)
                {
                    cpuResult[i*SEARCHITEMSIZE + j] = true;
                    for (int l = 0; l < keywordLengths[i]; l++)
                    {
                        if (dataPtr[j*MAXDATASTRINGSIZE + k + l] != keywordPtr[i*MAXKEYWORDSTRINGSSIZE + l])
                        {
                            cpuResult[i*SEARCHITEMSIZE + j] = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (cpuResult[i*SEARCHTERMSIZE + j])
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    endTime = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    millisecs_t duration3(chrono::duration_cast<millisecs_t>(endTime - startTime));
    cout << "CPU code ends: " << duration3.count() << "ms" << endl;
    /////////////////////////////////// CPU code //////////////////////////////////////////

    ////////////////////////////////////Result Comparison////////////////////////////////////////

    bool kernelRes = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < SEARCHITEMSIZE*SEARCHTERMSIZE; i++)
    {
        if (cpuResult[i] != result[i])
        {
            kernelRes = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////Result Comparison////////////////////////////////////////

    cout << boolalpha << "Kernel computation: " << kernelRes << endl;

    cout << "Before Deleting arrays" << endl;
    delete[] dataPtr;
    delete[] keywordPtr;
    delete[] dataLengths;
    delete[] keywordLengths;
    delete[] result;
    delete[] cpuResult;
    cout << "After Deleting arrays" << endl;

    cout << "Before Freeing device memory" << endl;
    cudaFree(d_dataPtr);
    cudaFree(d_keywordPtr);
    cudaFree(d_dataLengths);
    cudaFree(d_keywordLengths);
    cudaFree(d_resultPtr);
    cout << "After Freeing device memory" << endl;

    cudaDeviceReset();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Code for approach 2:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>

#define SEARCHTERMSIZE 198
#define SEARCHITEMSIZE 65000
#define MAXDATASTRINGSIZE 250
#define MAXKEYWORDSTRINGSSIZE 50

using namespace std;

__global__ void searchKeywordKernel(bool* resultPtr, const char  * __restrict__ dataPtr, const short*  dataLengths, const char *  keywordPtr, const short*  keywordLengths)
{
    int dataIndex = blockIdx.x;
    int keywordIndex = threadIdx.x;
    int dataLength = dataLengths[dataIndex];
    int keywordLength = keywordLengths[keywordIndex];
    __shared__ char sData[MAXDATASTRINGSIZE];

    if (dataIndex < SEARCHITEMSIZE)
    {
        int my_tid = keywordIndex;
        while (my_tid < dataLength)
        {
            sData[my_tid] = dataPtr[dataIndex*MAXDATASTRINGSIZE + my_tid];
            my_tid += blockDim.x;
        }
        __syncthreads();
        if (keywordIndex < SEARCHTERMSIZE)
        {
            if (dataLength < keywordLength)
            {
                resultPtr[dataIndex*SEARCHTERMSIZE + keywordIndex] = false;
            }
            else
            {
                bool isFound = true;
                for (int i = 0; i <= dataLength - keywordLength; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < keywordLength; j++)
                    {
                        if (sData[i + j] != keywordPtr[j*SEARCHTERMSIZE + keywordIndex])
                        {
                            isFound = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (isFound)
                        break;
                }
                resultPtr[dataIndex*SEARCHTERMSIZE + keywordIndex] = isFound;
            }
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    chrono::steady_clock::time_point startTime;
    chrono::steady_clock::time_point endTime;
    typedef chrono::duration<int, milli> millisecs_t;

    //////////Search Data Init/////////////////
    cout << "Before Search Data Init" << endl;
    startTime = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    char* dataPtr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAXDATASTRINGSIZE*SEARCHITEMSIZE);
    short* dataLengths = new short[SEARCHITEMSIZE];
    short temp;
    short tempChar;
    for (int i = 0; i < SEARCHITEMSIZE; i++)
    {
        temp = rand() % (MAXDATASTRINGSIZE - 20) + 20;
        for (int k = 0; k < temp; k++)
        {
            tempChar = rand() % 26;
            dataPtr[i*MAXDATASTRINGSIZE + k] = 97 + tempChar;  //97->a, 98->b, 122->z
        }
        dataLengths[i] = temp;
    }
    endTime = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    millisecs_t duration(chrono::duration_cast<millisecs_t>(endTime - startTime));
    cout << "After Search Data Init: " << duration.count() << "ms" << endl;
    //////////Search Data Init/////////////////

    //////////Search Keyword Init/////////////////
    cout << "Before Search Keyword Init" << endl;
    startTime = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    char* keywordPtr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAXKEYWORDSTRINGSSIZE*SEARCHTERMSIZE);
    short* keywordLengths = new short[SEARCHTERMSIZE]; //lenghts, not the start positions
    for (int i = 0; i < SEARCHTERMSIZE; i++)
    {
        temp = rand() % (MAXKEYWORDSTRINGSSIZE - 10) + 10;
        for (int k = 0; k < temp; k++)
        {
            tempChar = rand() % 26;
            keywordPtr[i*MAXKEYWORDSTRINGSSIZE + k] = 97 + tempChar;  //97->a, 98->b, 122->z
        }
        keywordLengths[i] = temp;
    }
    endTime = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    millisecs_t duration1(chrono::duration_cast<millisecs_t>(endTime - startTime));
    cout << "After Search Keyword Init: " << duration1.count() << "ms" << endl;
    //////////Search Keyword Init/////////////////  

    ////////////////////Traverse Keyword Array////////////////////////////

    char* keywordPtr_T = new char[SEARCHTERMSIZE*MAXKEYWORDSTRINGSSIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < SEARCHTERMSIZE; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < MAXKEYWORDSTRINGSSIZE; j++)
            keywordPtr_T[j*SEARCHTERMSIZE + i] = keywordPtr[i*MAXKEYWORDSTRINGSSIZE + j];

    ////////////////////Traverse Keyword Array////////////////////////////  

    char* d_dataPtr;
    short* d_dataLengths;
    char* d_keywordPtr;
    short* d_keywordLengths;
    bool* d_resultPtr;

    /////////////////////////CudaMalloc/////////////////////////////////
    cout << "Before Malloc" << endl;
    startTime = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    cudaMalloc(&d_dataPtr, sizeof(char) * SEARCHITEMSIZE * MAXDATASTRINGSIZE);
    cudaMalloc(&d_dataLengths, sizeof(short) * SEARCHITEMSIZE);
    cudaMalloc(&d_keywordPtr, sizeof(char) * SEARCHTERMSIZE*MAXKEYWORDSTRINGSSIZE);
    cudaMalloc(&d_keywordLengths, sizeof(short) * SEARCHTERMSIZE);
    cudaMalloc(&d_resultPtr, sizeof(bool)*SEARCHITEMSIZE * SEARCHTERMSIZE);

    endTime = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    millisecs_t duration2(chrono::duration_cast<millisecs_t>(endTime - startTime));
    cout << "After Malloc: " << duration2.count() << "ms" << endl;
    /////////////////////////CudaMalloc/////////////////////////////////

    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    float elapsedTime;

    /////////////////////////CudaMemCpy///////////////////////////////////
    cout << "Before Memcpy" << endl;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

    cudaMemcpy(d_dataPtr, dataPtr, sizeof(char) * SEARCHITEMSIZE * MAXDATASTRINGSIZE, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_dataLengths, dataLengths, sizeof(short) * SEARCHITEMSIZE, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_keywordPtr, keywordPtr_T, sizeof(char) * SEARCHTERMSIZE*MAXKEYWORDSTRINGSSIZE, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_keywordLengths, keywordLengths, sizeof(short) * SEARCHTERMSIZE, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsedTime, start, stop);
    cudaEventDestroy(start);
    cudaEventDestroy(stop);
    cout << "After Memcpy: " << elapsedTime << "ms" << endl;
    /////////////////////////CudaMemCpy///////////////////////////////////

    ////////////////////////Kernel//////////////////////////////////////////
    cout << "Before Kernel" << endl;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

    searchKeywordKernel << < SEARCHITEMSIZE, SEARCHTERMSIZE >> >(d_resultPtr, d_dataPtr, d_dataLengths, d_keywordPtr, d_keywordLengths);

    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsedTime, start, stop);
    cudaEventDestroy(start);
    cudaEventDestroy(stop);
    cout << "After Kernel: " << elapsedTime << "ms" << endl;
    ////////////////////////Kernel//////////////////////////////////////////

    bool* result_T = new bool[SEARCHTERMSIZE*SEARCHITEMSIZE];
    bool* result = new bool[SEARCHTERMSIZE*SEARCHITEMSIZE];

    cudaMemcpy(result_T, d_resultPtr, sizeof(bool) * SEARCHITEMSIZE * SEARCHTERMSIZE, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for (int i = 0; i < SEARCHTERMSIZE; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < SEARCHITEMSIZE; j++)
            result[j*SEARCHTERMSIZE + i] = result_T[i*SEARCHITEMSIZE + j];

    /////////////////////////////////// CPU code //////////////////////////////////////////

    bool* cpuResult = new bool[SEARCHTERMSIZE*SEARCHITEMSIZE];

    cout << "CPU code starts" << endl;
    startTime = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < SEARCHTERMSIZE; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < SEARCHITEMSIZE; j++)
        {
            if (dataLengths[j] < keywordLengths[i])
            {
                cpuResult[i*SEARCHITEMSIZE + j] = false;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int k = 0; k <= dataLengths[j] - keywordLengths[i]; k++)
                {
                    cpuResult[i*SEARCHITEMSIZE + j] = true;
                    for (int l = 0; l < keywordLengths[i]; l++)
                    {
                        if (dataPtr[j*MAXDATASTRINGSIZE + k + l] != keywordPtr[i*MAXKEYWORDSTRINGSSIZE + l])
                        {
                            cpuResult[i*SEARCHITEMSIZE + j] = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (cpuResult[i*SEARCHTERMSIZE + j])
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    endTime = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    millisecs_t duration3(chrono::duration_cast<millisecs_t>(endTime - startTime));
    cout << "CPU code ends: " << duration3.count() << "ms" << endl;
    /////////////////////////////////// CPU code //////////////////////////////////////////

    ////////////////////////////////////Result Comparison////////////////////////////////////////

    bool kernelRes = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < SEARCHITEMSIZE*SEARCHTERMSIZE; i++)
    {
        if (cpuResult[i] != result[i])
        {
            kernelRes = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////Result Comparison////////////////////////////////////////

    cout << boolalpha << "Kernel computation: " << kernelRes << endl;

    cout << "Before Deleting arrays" << endl;
    delete[] dataPtr;
    delete[] keywordPtr;
    delete[] keywordPtr_T;
    delete[] dataLengths;
    delete[] keywordLengths;
    delete[] result;
    delete[] result_T;
    delete[] cpuResult;
    cout << "After Deleting arrays" << endl;

    cout << "Before Freeing device memory" << endl;
    cudaFree(d_dataPtr);
    cudaFree(d_keywordPtr);
    cudaFree(d_dataLengths);
    cudaFree(d_keywordLengths);
    cudaFree(d_resultPtr);
    cout << "After Freeing device memory" << endl;

    cudaDeviceReset();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Second approach gave better results than the first approach. Yet the performance of the second approach depends on the number of keywords. If the number of the keywords is multiple of 192, gpu has performance than cpu (time of malloc+memcpy+kernel < time of cpu). 
What should I do to overcome such dependancy? 
 Would it be viable to increase the number of threads and to pass multiple data strings rather than one in each block?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest `blockDim = (16, 16, 1)` and `gridDim = (# of data strings / 16, # of keyword strings / 16, 1)`. In your case, where tens of strings can ideally fit in shared memory, such block-grid division will lead to minimum global memory access while introducing no computation overhead.

Padding is not a good choice, unless each string is expected to have its length quite close to the maximum (80% of maximum for example). If you keep a array of offset of every string (CPU is good at generating it), coalescing global memory read is just trivial.